# Cassandra Delete when row not exists

Tags: cassandra, delete-row

Is there a performance impact when running delete statements on cassandra when row doesn't exist? I am not passing the IF EXISTS clause in my delete statement as it adds an overhead of checking. I haven't found anything online about this unique use-case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete operation in Cassandra is just adding a marker called "tombstone" - it will be appended to the files with data to "hide" the previously existed data. It could have some performance impact on the read operations, if you have a lot of deletes inside partitions, etc. as tombstone usually kept for 10 days in the data file (configurable per table)

There is a [very interesting blog post on deletes and tombstones](https://thelastpickle.com/blog/2016/07/27/about-deletes-and-tombstones.html) - I recommend to read it.

Comment: I know about tombstones, my question is specifically for keys that do not exist (as in row not present). Will running deletes on non-existent data have a performance impact. For instance if i generate about 10 delete statements with only one statement having the primary keys will the other 9 actually incur a performance impact at all ?

Comment: Well, depending on your consistency level and your node count, even if Cassandra checks to see if there's already a tombstone before creating a new one you may still be writing tombstones for all your queries. But, I am betting it does not check since it doesn't check for other write operations so I think every one of the 10 queries will have the same performance impact.

Comment: Cassandra by default doesn’t check for existence of previous data. As I wrote, performance impact could  be on the read operations if you perform too many such deletes, and then, for example, run a Spark job

Comment: Okay I find it odd that tombstones will still be written on non-existent data. Are you implying for a unique primary key which doesn't exist and I push a delete Cassandra would create a row and then mark it with a tombstone. It does seem like the logical thing to do with a distributed database.

Comment: it's a tradeoff for performance - Cassandra is so much fast for writes because it doesn't incur any reading of data (except for lightweight transactions) - the data is just added to the memtable... btw, tombstones are generated also for things like collections, and UDTs - because there could be previous data, and new data are partial, Cassandra need to make sure that no previous data survive